# Detect simple lines in binary image (vector of lines)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, line, graph-theory

I have a simple binary image of a graph with thin lines, where the goal is to create a vector of separate edges/lines from the image below - the overall objective is to create an adjacency graph (data structure).

[image: binary GVD]

So far, I've used `cv::HoughLinesP()` which gives some, but not all, edges. I can draw these edges/lines by iterating the vector they're stored in.

```cpp
// perform probabilistic hough line extraction
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> vec_lines;
cv::HoughLinesP(
    img_edges,    // input img (from edge detector)
    vec_lines,    // ouput vector of [x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end] for each line
    1,            // resolution of parameter rho in pixels
    CV_PI/180,    // resolution of theta in radians
    10,           // minimum number of intersections to “detect” a line
    5,            // minimum number of points that can form a line
    0             // maximum gap between two points to be considered in the same line
);

// draw lines
for (const auto& l : vec_lines)
    cv::line(img_out, cv::Point(l[0], l[1]), cv::Point(l[2], l[3]), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 1, 8);
```

Which results in something like this:

[image: edges-attempt]

Are the parameters insufficient or is there a better approach?

Comment: Did you try to modify the 3 last parameters `threshold`, `minLineLength` and `maxLineGap` ? Perhaps your `minLineLength` (5 in your case) is too big?

Comment: Maybe you can acheive that with better accuracy  by iterating through those segments and detect where the  prev and next point's are not collinear ...  you can also try opencv LSD .

Comment: @LucieBoursier I've tried playing a bit with the values, but I can't seem to find the right ones.

@Ziri I'm not exactly sure what you mean, and opencv LSD is not available due to licensing issues.. I was thinking about using the simple `HoughLines()` and find where each detected line it matches a segment of white pixels.